# Is it possible to hide the specific area of a CSS background sprite image using clip?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to hide the specific area of a `CSS` `background image` using `clip`? for example I have multiple icons on image but I want to show only one icon. Because area of Div is greater then the icon size so other unneeded icons are also showing. Can I hide them without making another image for that single icon?

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/FyMW6/1/

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you create a container for each image which you use to dictate the area of the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/FyMW6/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="button">
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>  
    <div id="house" class="icons"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button {     
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid red
}

.text {
    float: left;
    width: 245px;
}

.icons {
    background-image: url("http://www.smtusa.com/uploads/cssexample.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
}

#house {
    background-position: -56px -45px;
}

#gear {
    background-position: -56px -106px;
}
```

Comment: As @Pekka said it's not possible with CSS `clip` and `Background-Clip` but your solution will work for me.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think so, at least not in CSS2.

You can't apply the `clip` property to a background image.

<strike>CSS3 has the [`background-clip`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-clip) property that seems to do exactly what you need. It comes with limited browser support at the moment, though.</strike> CSS has the `background-clip` property but it allows only to specify which bounding box the image is rendered in.

There may be no solution for this except using another container for the icon.

Comment: @Jitendra I was too hasty, sorry. `background-clip` doesn't do exactly what you need. There may be no solution for this without using a separate container

Comment: @Pekka- I added jsfiddle example

Comment: @Jitendra I think it's simply not possible, you'll have to have a separate container for the icon (with the proper size)

Comment: OK. CSS Sprite is no possible evertime :)

Answer (score -1):

easiest way  is to set the class to display: none;